# Find out what file is requiring another file in Node

Tags: node.js, require

The title says pretty much what I need to do.

I have a module in node_modules which prints something to the standard output (and I don't want this to happen) but I don't find where I'm requiring this file.

I may be misunderstanding how modules are included, as I though that they must be required in order to be executed.

Comment: https://remysharp.com/2014/05/23/where-is-that-console-log

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your module and look at the call stack to see what called `require()` to load your module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways for stuff to write to output.  If it's just using `console.log()`, just swap in trace.  Before your `require()` statements:

```
console.log = console.trace;
```

Then, you'll have the full trace output every time there's a log.

Answer (score 2):

Using this `console.log` mod :

```
let old = console.log;
console.log = function(){
 return old.apply(this,[].slice.apply(arguments).concat([(new Error()).stack.split(/\n/)[2].trim()]));
}
```

If you try :

```
console.log('I am trackable!')
```

You will get as output :

```
I am trackable! at test (/path/solution.js:5:9)
```

Happy hunting!